Build multiple C# project configurations simultaneously with .csproj variables
Imagine having a mathematics library, which provides some functionality optimized for IEEE754 number types. The code might have something along the lines of:
#if F16
    global using Scalar = System.Half;
#elif F32
    global using Scalar = System.Single;
#elif F32
    global using Scalar = System.Double;
#endif

// ...

or
#if F32
    public static float HighlyOptimizedMethod(float a, float b, float c) { ... };
#elif F64
    public static double HighlyOptimizedMethod(double a, double b, double c) { ... };
#endif

I now define those preprocessor constants F16, F32, F64 in my .csproj project file as follows:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- change the following for different precisions. -->
        <!--<Scalar>F16</Scalar>-->
        <!--<Scalar>F32</Scalar>-->
        <Scalar>F64</Scalar>

        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);$(Scalar)</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>

        <AssemblyName Condition="'$(Scalar)' != ''">mylibrary.$(Scalar)</AssemblyName>
        <AssemblyName Condition="'$(Scalar)' == ''">mylibrary</AssemblyName>
    
        ...
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

My question
Is it possible to make VisualStudio/dotnet/MSBuild create the assemblies for all three configurations at the same time when building the project? i.e. would it be possible to run 'compile' and then have the following file list in the bin/ directory?

mylibrary.F16.dll
mylibrary.F32.dll
mylibrary.F64.dll

I tried fiddling around with something like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- change the following for different precisions. if all are commented out, every configuration will be built. -->
   
        <!--<Scalar>F16</Scalar>-->
        <!--<Scalar>F32</Scalar>-->
        <Scalar>F64</Scalar>

        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);$(Scalar)</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="BuildOthers" BeforeTargets="CoreBuild" Condition="'$(Scalar)' == ''">
        <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Scalar=F16" />
        <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Scalar=F32" />
        <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Scalar=F64" />
    </Target>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>

        ...

But it didn't get it to work.
May someone be able to help me and/or point me into the right direction?
Thanks.

There is generic math that may let you write a generic method that handles multiple different types of numbers. It may not allow all kinds of optimization, but if you need to optimize at that level, why not just have multiple overloads? What do you hope to gain from creating different dlls for different data types?

@JonasH my point was NOT about the generic math part, I know that. it was about using variables in .csproj and building multiple compile targets at once.
I should have used an other example .....

Well, the use case is quite unclear to me. There is multi targeting of different .Net versions or platforms. But I have no idea if the same approach can be used for whatever you want to do.

@unknown6656 You could create multiple configurations in the project and, in the VS IDE, batch build all the "Release | Configuration" combinations of interest. Projects are intended and designed to build one "target" per build. Multi-targeting is actually implemented by building the project multiple times, once for each target. You could create a utility project using the "Microsoft.Build.NoTargets" SDK that just builds your project multiple times with different configurations.

Hi @unknown6656, on the base of what you try with  target BuildOthers, i suggest you can add a copy task to  copy .dll files to bin folder.


would it be possible to run 'compile' and then have the following file list in the bin/ directory?

Yes. You can check the following like this:
<PropertyGroup>
 <Scalar>''</Scalar>
 <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Scalar=F16" />
    <Copy
       SourceFiles="\obj\Debug\net8.0\mylibrary.F16.dll"
       DestinationFolder="bin\$(Configuration)\Resources"
    />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Scalar=F32" />
    <Copy
       SourceFiles="\obj\Debug\net8.0\mylibrary.F32.dll"
       DestinationFolder="bin\$(Configuration)\Resources"
    />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Scalar=F64" />
    <Copy
       SourceFiles="\obj\Debug\net8.0\mylibrary.F64.dll"
       DestinationFolder="bin\$(Configuration)\Resources"
    />
</Target>


But it didn't get it to work(target BuildOthers)

Based on my test, i found the mylibrary.F12.dll and mylibrary.F32.dll are removed by target IncrementalClean.
1.delte mylibrary.F12.dll after generating mylibrary.F32.dll

2.delte mylibrary.F32.dll after generating mylibrary.F64.dll

As we know, IncrementalClean will remove files that were produced in a prior build. In this mode, it is not possible to have the three .dll file in bin folder when run msbuild. To prevent files to be removed during incremental build, you can add <copy> task to copy .dll files to bin folder.
Also you can try to disable incremental build. For more information, please read doc:--no-incremental
Besides, as the easiest way to achieve it ,you can try @Jonathan suggestion.
Here is a similar ticket you can refer:
How to create multiple assets (dll) for one project with msbuild depend on Constants value?
